# Ubuntu Software and Ubuntu Software Center problems on 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have not found a way to install third party apps yet in the Ubuntu Software store. I saw some posts about using terminal to update and ran those commands as well. I have even tried adding the old Ubuntu Software Center instead, but when I try to use it it says there is a problem with the repository. So far, there have been no successful fixes. Any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/908767/edit) your question and add information about which software you are trying to install. Particularly, indicate the file type, such as `deb`, `zip`, `exe` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on the third party Software.

As far as I know the Software-Center is just a graphical Front-end for apt-get.

In `/etc/apt/sources.list` you might have to add the repository required for the third party software you want to install.

(There already some lines commented out that maybe already archive what you are going to install)

Answer (score 0):

Please specify which software which you want to install. I think it will solved by enabling the software source ( universe, canonical etc. ) and try to update your system via command line.